# angular not being detected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This is very weird situation. I have following folder structure

```
├── angular.min.js
├── app.js
├── bootstrap.min.css
└── tenant.html
```

and this is my `tenant.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="condos">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        1 + 2
        {{'hello'}}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

When i preview this file, I don't see angular expressions `{{}}` being executed. I can't figure out what i am missing :s

here is my `app.js`

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('condos',[]);

})();
```

Comment: Should work as is, what does your browsers net tab say, getting any 404s when requesting angular?

Comment: Ps type text JavaScript not needed for html5 i would drop it - but that's irrelevant for the purposes of a solution - what does your net tab say?

Comment: This works fine? [PLUNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/d8Fb7o8OjUFdXOLKAaS7?p=preview)

Comment: I was using Atom preview tab to check it. Seems like it wasn't working properly. once i opened it on chrome, everything worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

You might need a controller for the brackets to work

try adding

```
app.controller('myCtrl',function(){});
```

and `<body ng-controller="myCtrl">`

Comment: A controller isn't needed for what the OP wants to acheive